# Update firestore data from populated recycler View

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update firestore data which I have got in a Recycler view.

> Recycler View Activity Code

```
class AdminActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val dB = Firebase.firestore

private lateinit var userRecyclerView: RecyclerView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    supportActionBar?.title = "Admin Panel"

    userRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.user_list)
    userRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    userRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)


    val query = dB.collection("users")
    val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>().setQuery(query, User::class.java)
        .setLifecycleOwner(this).build()

    //adapter
    val adapter = object : FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(options) {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(this@AdminActivity)
                .inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false)
            return UserViewHolder(view)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int, model: User) {
            val nameTv: TextView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_textview)
            val idTv: TextView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_textview)
            val phoneTv: TextView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_textview)

            nameTv.text = model.name
            idTv.text = model.id
            phoneTv.text = model.phone

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(baseContext, AdminViewActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    userRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

}
```

}

I want to update the data when i click on the holder.
Only update the data of the user whose recycler view I clicked.
[Firestore Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU71t.jpg)

Comment: "I want to update the data when i click on the holder."  doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly would you like to update?

Comment: I want to be able to change the firestore data's from each recycler view and update it on firestore. @AlexMamo

Comment: Like an admin app where only specific person can change users data @AlexMamo

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or even this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help. It deletes, and not updates, but I think it can help you get an idea.